# getting the mean value of a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get the mean value of a spectogram, for that I use  :

```
X = spectogram(x,hamming(512),128,3000:4000,96e3,'yaxis');
```

where `x` is my data. the result that get is 1001x3749 complex double, I would to the mean or the average value of the whole matrix, I tried to :

```
mean(X(:,:),2);
mean(X)
mean2(X);
```

It doesn't delivere me, what  I want which is one value that represents the mean value like :

for

```
A = [1 1 1 , 1 1 1 ,1 1 1 ];
```

the answer would be 1

any idea how can I do that  ?

Comment: Make a column vector of it and get the mean - `mean(X(:))` If it's 2D, I would think `mean2` to work too.

Comment: that Divakar, if you put it as answer I'll accept it

Comment: Just curious is `X` 2D? Is X that `1001x3749 complex double`?

Comment: I am not sure what you want here. There are two ways of calculating mean, use mean 2 times, to get the mean per column first and then mean of all means (or rowwise first by calling mean(X,2)): Or simply reshaping it to to a vector as divakar did. The result is not the same. But the first method is best if the test data is stored as one column per test and the second one if all data is on sequence (bet you knew that). However, mean2 seems to give the exact same result as divakars method `mean(A(:))-mean2(A),  ans = 0`. So what I wonder is, what mean are you after?

Comment: @Divakar thanks it works and yes its 2D complex double

Comment: @Engine So `mean2(X)` didn't work before, but now it is? Since `mean2` is particularly made for such cases, I would support that rather. And since it's already in your question, it doesn't make sense to post an answer of it.

Comment: I think that I missunderstood the mean2 function I was hope to get a matrix filled with mean2 result and not only one elements but indeed it work both with mean2 and  X(:), @patrik I need those for the second case

Comment: @Engine if you want a matrix filled with the `mean2` result value that is easy to get `Xnew = mean2(X)*ones(size(X))`. If you mean that you want something else, like a weighted average based on some criterion, then this will certainly not work, there is no easy answer to that question anyway

Comment: thanks I 've already done it